# How to use MFC with ATL

Tags: com, mfc, atl

I'm trying to write a COM EXE using ATL. I also have a MFC application.
Both these applications would be run in local machines. Therefore, I don't
need to run these two processes (COM EXE and MFC) separately.

Can I create a single application (process) by combining these two applications ?
Is there any possibility that I can embed my MFC code in ATL code, or
is there a way to initialize the COM EXE within my MFC code ?

Appreciate your help and concerns .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code more reusable by moving your ATL objects to a new ATL COM DLL project and make your two exe projects clients of your ATL objects.

If you add an ATL object to a MFC project without ATL support, Visual C++ will prompt you to add ATL support. You can then cancel the wizard without really adding an ATL object, but the ATL support will remain,